# Calculate difference between rows based on two groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm currently working on a dataset that consists of several variables, extracted from WRDS. The data contains information about the company (GVKEY), Return on Assets (ROA), and fiscal year (FYEAR). I want to calculate the change in ROA per *year* per *company*. The dataframe consists of approximately 4000 firms with several firm-year observations. The dataframe (df_industry) looks as follows:

```
GVKEY FYEAR ROA
100   2001  0.34
100   2002  0.33
100   2003  0.66
100   2004  0.49
100   2005  0.20
202   2001  0.34
202   2004  0.99
202   2005  0.12
202   2006  0.78
202   2007  0.23
202   2008  0.89
```

I've tried several solutions using the dplyr package, such as summarise and mutate, but they continue seem to continue their calculations despite grouping per GVKEY.

```
df_industry %>% group_by(FYEAR) %>% mutate(roa_difference = ROA - lag(ROA))
```

I'd like to add a column (roa_difference) that calculates the difference in ROA with the previous year, and if there's no data about the previous year to display NA. Current results continue calculations irregardless of company, resulting in incorrect data for the first observation of a new company.

Answer (score 1):

you were almost right, you want to group_by compagny no ?
Is this code working for you need :

```
df <- data.frame(GVKEY = rep(100, 4), FYEAR = seq(2001, 2004, 1), ROA = c(0.34, 0.33, 0.66, 0.49))

df %>%
  arrange(FYEAR) %>%
  group_by(GVKEY) %>%
  mutate(roa_difference = ROA - lag(ROA))
```

Comment: This is great answer but I think it works as the data is already ordered by FYEAR.  If the data wasn't already sorted the lag function wouldn't work reliably.  The easiest fix for this is to add `arrange(FYEAR) %>%` between `group_by` and the `mutate` function.  This will compel the correct ordering of the data frame.